# Where does Debian 8.1 install adduser?

Tags: debian, software-installation, path

Code and outputs

```
apt-cache search adduser
adduser - add and remove users and groups
$ sudo apt-get install adduser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
adduser is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ add
add-apt-repository  addpart             addr2line           
$ which adduser
$ echo $PATH
/home/masi/bin:/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

which I do not understand since it says that I have `adduser` but it is not in the PATH although I have most `bin` folders. 
There must be other location where `adduser` is added in Debian 8.1.

Where is `adduser` installed in Debian 8.1?

Comment: I find it at `/usr/sbin/adduser`.

Comment: @fd0 Please, make that an answer. You are correct! I do not understand why this PATH is not set correctly by default. I put `PATH="$HOME/bin:/sbin/:/usr/sbin/:$PATH"` in my $HOME/.bashrc.

Comment: PATH *is* set correctly by default - with `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` for root, and without them for normal users.  What did you expect?

Comment: @Masi There is no need to add `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` to your PATH. The secure path is set in `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @fd0 Yes, you are so right. Thank you for pointing that out! Please, make the edit to your answer to your answer too, not to confuse people reading this thread afterwards. Just login first by `sudo -i` and search `add[tab]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I'm looking for a tool I first look to see if it is in my PATH.

```
    type adduser
    bash: type: adduser: not found
```

If it is not found then I'll use `apropos`

```
    apropos adduser
    add.user.conf (5) - configuration file for adduser (8) and addgroup (8) .
    adduser (8)       - add a user or group to the system
```

Section 8 is System administration commands and daemons. So, I would look in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`. `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are left out of a normal user's PATH for security and many of those commands require root privileges to run. Both are added to your path by `/etc/sudoers` when you preference a command with `sudo`.

Comment: So "S" for System. Thank you for your answer!